# How do you change label alignment in PyQt6?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

I'm following the tutorial found here:

```
https://zetcode.com/pyqt6/layout/
```

Here is the python:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit,
        QTextEdit, QGridLayout, QApplication)



class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        contact = QLabel('Contact Name')
        title = QLabel('Contact Title')
        phone = QLabel('Direct Line')
        email = QLabel('Email')
        notes = QLabel('Notes')

        contactEdit = QLineEdit()
        titleEdit = QLineEdit()
        phoneEdit = QLineEdit()
        emailEdit = QLineEdit()
        notesEdit = QTextEdit()

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(15)

        grid.addWidget(contact, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(contactEdit, 1, 1)

        grid.addWidget(title, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(titleEdit, 2, 1)

        grid.addWidget(phone, 3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(phoneEdit, 3, 1)

        grid.addWidget(email, 4, 0)
        grid.addWidget(emailEdit, 4, 1)

        grid.addWidget(notes, 5, 0)
        grid.addWidget(notesEdit, 5, 1)

        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.resize(400, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Review')
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This create 5 labels, 4 QLineEdits and the last label is for a QTextEdit. The labels are aligned vertically centered, for the last label I would like to align it to the top. Here is my attempt at it:

```
notes = QLabel('Notes').AlignTop()
```

But I was getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'QLabel' object has no attribute 'AlignTop'
```

Comment: Please don't try to randomly make up functions: always look at the documentation. Also, even if that function *would* have existed, using it like that would result in having `notes` equal to `None` (and, anyway, it would be named `alignTop`, with a lowercase first letter). Change to `grid.addWidget(notes, 5, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop)` and add `from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt` to the imports. Then carefully study the explanation about [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) and the documentation of all of its classes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I found AlignTop over here: ```https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#AlignmentFlag-enum```. Nevertheless, thanks for the comment

Comment: That is a flag, not a function, and as such is normally intended as an argument of a function (as shown in my comment above). It's a "value", like a string or a number. If you don't understand the difference, I strongly urge you to do more research on the matter, as you cannot ignore such basic aspects in programming.

Answer (score 2):

You have alignment flags under the Qt class in the QtCore module. Import it and set alignment on the `notes` label like this:

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
...
notes = QLabel('Notes', alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop)
```